# When to use JPA locking?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm developing a simple Spring Boot CRUD application using JPA that manages products in a DB. This application behaves as expected in my testing in that products can be created, read, updated and deleted. Now I'm considering how this application will perform in a concurrent environment.

Reading https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-optimistic-locking which describes handling "multiple transactions in an effective and most importantly, error-proof way." But is this not handled by the Spring Boot framework? I've encountered CRUD apps in the past and never encountered locking being explicitly implemented. I assumed that any DB updates are thread-safe and locking is not required to be implemented explicitly but is this not always true?

Should I use locking to calculate for example product inventory? So if I have 3 products and 3 GET requests are invoked to read 1,2 and 3 product respectively there is a risk that one of the threads will access a product that the DB has not updated insufficient time to indicate that the product is no longer available as other threads have exhausted the inventory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optimistic locking helps to prevent that you change something having old information of the entity.

Imagine the following scenario:

You have an Product entity and this product a purchase and a selling price.

Imagine one thread loads the enitity from the database and the purchase price is 10 dollar and the selling price is 12 dollar.

The code adjusts the selling price to 15 dollar but before this change is commited to the database another thread is also modifying the entity.

The other thread adjusted the purchase price and increased it to 20 dollar and this change is already committed to the database.

I'm pretty sure you do not want to set the selling price to 15 dollar if the purchase price is 20 dollar.

With optimistic locking the framework (i.e. hiberate) checks whether the entity that shall be saved is in the same state that it was when it has been loaded from the database. Otherwise it will throw a OptimisticLockingException.
If the purchase price is still 10 dollar changing the selling price to 15 dollar is fine. But if the purchase price has changed somehow in the meantime the optimistic locking helps you to not set a new selling price on outdated information (in this case that the purchase price is 10 dollar)